# Tools for searching string literals in an application

Tags: c#, asp.net

Are there any tools for locating all the strings that I've to Internationalize?
My app is already "partially" designed for Internationalization support. However I want to make sure that there arent' any hardcoded string within my app.

Regular expression search didn't help a lot as trying to find "***" returns every aspx page.

Are there any tools to do this?

Answer (score 3):

### [FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476(VS.80).aspx)

"FxCop is an application that analyzes managed code assemblies (code that targets the .NET Framework common language runtime) and reports information about the assemblies, such as possible design, localization, performance, and security improvements. Many of the issues concern violations of the programming and design rules set forth in the Design Guidelines for Class Library Developers, which are the Microsoft guidelines for writing robust and easily maintainable code by using the .NET Framework."

See: [Globalization Warnings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182184(VS.80).aspx) → [Do not pass literals as localized parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182187(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: You need to make use of the [Localizable] attribute on your properties to get the best out of FxCop.

Comment: I don't see the "Do not pass literals as localized parameters" option in FxCop. Moreover, how can I use this on a ASP.NET project?

Comment: @Mugunth: Web Application Project or Web Site Project (former created through new project, latter through new web site). For a Web Application Project FXCop is available in project settings under Code Analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans and Eclipse support this out of the box. I think it is even enabled by default.
I don't know about Visual Studio, but I'd expect that it offers such functionality.

In eclipse and with java it works like this:
  Whenever the integrated compiler sees a string literal it issues a warning unless the string literal is marked with a //$NON-NLS-1$ comment.

In Netbeans it is mostly the same but you mark non-translatable string literals (regexes, SQL, ...) with NOI18N.